# Is it possible to have a solar system where none of the celestial bodies seem to be rotating or orbiting?

Tags: solar-system

Individual tidally locked planets or moons are a relatively common topic, but I was wondering if it would at all be possible for an entire solar system's celestial bodies to orbit and rotate at just the right speeds to make it seem like none of the bodies are moving at all and that, to an observer standing on one of the planets, only the stars themselves seem to be moving along the night sky. Basically everything would be so tidally locked to everything else that if you used a telescope on one of the planets you'd always see the same sides to everything at all times and they'd never move from their position in the night sky, except for the stars of other solar systems.

**Can an entire solar system's celestial bodies have just the right orbital and rotational speeds be locked in this way?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For a naturally evolving planetary system, it is very unlikely.

But if you hire even a novice planetary system engineer, s/he will arrange for you a system with as many planets as you want (more than two, though) so "that, to an observer standing on one of the planets, only the stars themselves seem to be moving along the night sky."

The trick is to make all the planets of equal mass and distribute them equally spaced on a circular orbit around the central star. Tidal locking them to the central star is a given, yes

A slightly more professional planetary system engineer may throw in some minor celestial bodies, also equally spaces in the generalized Lagrange points of such a system.

---

A mind-blowing "practical" extension on the idea in the answer - highly grateful to @ARogueAnt. for posting it in the comments [The Ultimate Engineered Solar System](https://planetplanet.net/2017/05/03/the-ultimate-engineered-solar-system/). Let the numbers speak for themselves:

> The Sun’s habitable zone can fit 57 mega-Earths (10 Earth-mass planets), 252 Earths, or a whopping 1157 Marses!  Holy banana pancakes Batman!

Comment: Beat me to it. Even the Lagrange moons too. There's someone who's designed a solar system based on this but I can't find the ref..

Comment: @ARogueAnt. "There's someone who's designed a solar system based on this but I can't find the ref.." With symmetry is not even hard, high school knowledge/skills are enough. As a bonus, I'm trying to find some "stellar choreographies" - which a periodic not-elliptic solutions to equal mass n-body problem. A solution for a 3-body choreography is the classical [8-figure](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iuRtNK2-jO8). Here's a [4-body one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BG0Oi1muq_0)

Comment: Fair enough about the skills, but I was referring to a frequently cited and rather impressive set of YouTube animations, similar idea, but with several suns etc. - essentially designing massive choreographed systems of bodies unlikely in nature.

Comment: @ARogueAnt. oh, it means that we're likely searching for the same thing. It was way easier back in early 2000 to find the, right now I get only links to music and shopping.

Comment: @ARogueAnt. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-body_choreography#External_links The references too, I seem to remember  the arxiv ones (but this for later, my last meeting of the day in just starts)

Comment: @ARogueAnt.:  Are you remembering Sean Raymond's ["Ultimate Solar System"?](https://planetplanet.net/the-ultimate-solar-system/)

Comment: YES. The one with the [42 planets in the same orbit](https://planetplanet.net/2017/05/03/the-ultimate-engineered-solar-system/) - stable and appearing to stand still. I'm sure that I remember someone creating some rather splendid graphics to go with it somewhere else.

Comment: @ARogueAnt. I'm left 

Comment: How stable would this be? Is there anything keeping the planets from drifting away from the equally-spaced distribution as the orbits are perturbed over time (by passing stars and rogue planets, if nothing else)?

Comment: @CharlesStaats see the link in -at-ARogueAnt.'s comment (which I took in the body of my answer). The guy that crammed 42 Earths on a single circular orbit simulated the behaviour for small perturbations and reached the conclusion the solution is stable.

Comment: @CharlesStaats reading it more carefully, it seems that I need to retract or amend what I said about stability to small perturbations. As of now, it's unclear yet for me the amount of stability or instability in the system, but I'm running out of spare time to check on it. When you have time, give that article a read, the comments included - it worth it.

Answer (score 2):

You couldn't have more than one planet, but if you had only one planet it could happen.

The planet would have to have the same orbital period around the star as the rotation period of the star, and it would have to be tidally locked.

It could also not have a moon as then that moon would be seen revolving around the planet.

I'm sure it's possible that such a system could evolve naturally, but it's going to be a very low chance probably of such a thing happening given how precise all things would have to fall in place.

For that planet to then have a zone where life can evolve, and for it to actually do so, makes it even more unlikely. For that life than to develop intelligence to the point it can make for an interesting race to base your story around, even more unlikely.

Comment: " to have the same orbital period around the star as the rotation period " - to my mind, that's not an issue. The surface of the start will never be the same, the chaotic nature of the normal stellar process will guarantee you will never see the same "geographical formations" on the star surface. Unless the star is absolutely homogeneous (IDK, like a neutron star), but then it wouldn't matter if you are looking at the same star "face" or another.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi we know our star rotates because of observations of the solar surface from earth.

Answer (score 2):

## Try a hierarchy of similar orbital periods

The orbital period is 2 pi sqrt(r^3/m), where r is the radius of the orbit (has to be circular here!) and m is the reduced mass of the system (approximately, mass of the larger object).

Start with a binary star system and put your planet at, oh, the L4 point of the smaller star.  If you tidally lock it, the stars are always at the same position in the sky.

Now, make the planet, say, 1/2000 the mass of one of the stars.  (1/1000 of their reduced mass).  Then a moon should revolve around it with the same period, if it is at 1/10 the distance between the stars.

Now, make a submoon, say, 1/125 the mass of the planet, revolving at 1/5 the distance of the moon from the planet... and perhaps others at the Trojan points of the *planet* relative to the stars.

I will admit, this is a many-body problem and I am handwaving at things like Hill spheres ... you're going to need a proper simulation to know.  But it ought to be possible to come up with *something*...

Answer (score 1):

Tidal locking work from one body to only another one. E.g. our Moon is tidally locked to us, and we always see the same side, but to an observer on another planet it appears to be rotating and its whole surface will (in principle) be visible.

Take Pluto: it's tidally locked to its satellite Charon, but we have been able to see it rotating and determine the duration of its day.

If you wait long enough (probably longer than the star life) an entire solar system can develop tidal locking to either the central star or the most attractive body around (with attractive I mean exercising the greatest tidal influence), but you would still be seeing those bodies revolving.